# showing expectation of an estimator for a binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory

A random variable X is modelled as a binomial distribution with  parameters $n$ and $p$.

1. Show that $P= \dfrac{x}{n}$ is an unbiased estimatror of $p$.

This preceding is easy I have shown it to be true i.e $E(P) =p$.

But how does the following part work ?

Let $U = nP(1-P)$

2. Show that $E(U) = (n-1)p(1-p)$.

Please help ; the issue is why not $np - np^2$.?

Answer (score 1):

Note:
$$\mathbb E(P)=\mathbb E\left(\frac Xn\right)=\frac1n\mathbb E(X)=\frac1n\cdot np=p.$$
$$\mathbb E(U)=\mathbb E(nP(1-P))=\mathbb E\left(n\cdot \frac{X}{n}\cdot \left(1-\frac Xn\right)\right)=\\
\mathbb E\left(X-\frac{X^2}{n}\right)=\mathbb E(X)-\mathbb E\left(\frac{X^2}{n}\right)=np-\frac{1}{n}\cdot \mathbb E(X^2)=\\
np-\frac 1n\cdot \left(Var(X)+(\mathbb E(X))^2\right)=np-\frac 1n\cdot(np(1-p)+(np)^2)=\\
np-p(1-p)-np^2=np(1-p)-p(1-p)=(n-1)p(1-p). $$

Comment: great guys.... got it thanks , though in the first answer we can use np(1-p)

Answer (score 0):

As you must be aware by now, for an estimator $W(\theta)$ of a parameter $\theta$, it is not in general that $\operatorname{E}[g(W)] = g(\operatorname{E}[W])$ for some function $g$, even if $W$ is unbiased for $\theta$.  In your case, you mistakenly presumed that for $g(x) = x(1-x)$, $W = P = X/n$, and $\theta = p$, you have $$\operatorname{E}[P(1-P)] = \operatorname{E}[P](1 - \operatorname{E}[P]).$$
Although the solution was already provided in another answer, a slightly shorter computation can be made via completing the square.  Since $\operatorname{E}[P] = p$, we write  $$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}[P(1-P)] &= \operatorname{E}[P-P^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[p^2 + (1-2p)P - p^2 + 2pP - P^2] \\
&= p^2 + (1-2p)\operatorname{E}[P] - \operatorname{E}[(P - p)^2] \\
&= p^2 + (1-2p)p - \operatorname{Var}[P] \\
&= p^2 + p - 2p^2 - \frac{p(1-p)}{n} \\
&= \frac{(n-1)}{n} p(1-p), \end{align*}$$
and the result follows.